# android searchview getSearchableInfo throws nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android

I was trying to implement sample search interface in MainActivity with searchview widget. But it keeps throwing null pointer exception at getSearchableInfo in the onCreateOptionsMenu method of MainActivity.

I already have tried the following things, but nothing has helped. Its just a sample code and its giving me a hard time.:

- Using android.support.v7.widget.SearchView or using android.widget.SearchView in menu xml item and the onCreateOptionsMenu of MainActivity.
- Using MenuItemCompat or using menu in onCreateOptionsMenu.
- Using just getComponentName() or using new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class).
- Using full path or using relative path for SearchActivity in AndroidManifest.
- Adding following line in proguard-android.txt : -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Process: com.mycompany.testsearch, PID: 17480
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mycompany.testsearch.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2546)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:979)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:118)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are my code files:

1] AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.testsearch" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchableActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"
            android:value=".activities.SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

2] Main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:TestSearch="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/my_exp_search"
    android:title="action bar search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    TestSearch:showAsAction="always"
    TestSearch:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    TestSearch:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

3] Searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/hint_text"
android:includeInGlobalSearch="true">
</searchable>
```

4] MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
//SearchManager searchManager =     
//(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
//SearchView searchView =      
//(SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.my_exp_search).getActionView();
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_exp_search);
    SearchView searchView = 
   (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);         
searchView.setSearchableInfo(
       searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
//        String pkg = "com.mycompany.testsearch";
//        String cls = "com.mycompany.testsearch.SearchActivity";
//        ComponentName mycomponent = new ComponentName(pkg,cls);             
searchView.setSearchableInfo(
          searchManager.getSearchableInfo(mycomponent));
 searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
 return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

5] SearchActivity:

```
public class SearchableActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d("test","Reached searchable");
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        TextView textView = 
               (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_message);
        textView.setText(query);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        TextView textView = 
                (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_message);
        textView.setText(query);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is     
//present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_searchable, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you please post stack trace here.